# Backbone.Collection.where error Uncaught TypeError: i.matches is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections, backbone-model

I just started work with backbone.js and I have some issue. Sample of code:

```
var Product = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    id: 0,
    category: 0,
    material: '',
    capacity: 0,
    sharpe: 0
  },
  initialize: function(){
    console.log( this.get('id') );
  },
  Show: function() {
    $(".products__item_" + this.get('id')).show('fast');
  }
});

var Products = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Product
}); 

var products = new Products();

$( ".products__item" ).each(function( index ) {
  var product = new Product({ 
    id: $(this).data('id'),
    category: $(this).data('category'),
    material: $(this).data('material'),
    capacity: $(this).data('capacity'),
    sharpe: $(this).data('sharpe') 
  });
  products.add(product);
});

var temp = products.where({ id: 3272 })
```

So when I try run where on Backbone.Collection I get `Uncaught TypeError: i.matches is not a function` error. Any idea what I do wrong?

Comment: The code that iterates over `".products__item"`, `show()` method etc (*most of the DOM manipulation*) should be ideally part of a `Backbone.View`. It'll be helpful if you can create a demo snippet or fiddle demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Looks good to me.. Im guessing its because of `order of operations` youre running the `where()` before loading the data.

http://jsfiddle.net/8ru16k5v/

```
var products = new Backbone.Collection(); 

products.add({
    id: 3271,
    category: 10,
    material: 'wood',
    capacity: 10,
    sharpe: 10
});
products.add({
    id: 3272,
    category: 0,
    material: 'steal',
    capacity: 10,
    sharpe: 40
})

var temp = products.where({ id: 3272 })[0].toJSON()
console.log(temp)
alert(JSON.stringify(temp))
```

PS. please dont do the `Show()` in side the model. Make a `Backbone.View`, attach your collection to that. And use `events` like `collection.on('sync', doSomethingImportant)`

Comment: *"order of operations youre running the where() before loading the data*"- Why do you think so..?

He seems to be calling `where()` after adding products in loop.